# What is the logic behind mergeSort for merging subArrays?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I have been searching for a visual representation of Merge Sort in the form of stack logic. Since we call the function recursively, I cannot shape in my mind that how we merge the sorted subarray further. As far as I understood, we first divide the problem into sub-problems. We do this by calling the MergeSort algorithm which works recursively by calling itself with the start and end index of the divided sub-arrays. Then we call the Merge function which sorts the array elements. Yet what I cannot understand is that after making the recursive calls, we come to the point of sorting the elements. In that part, we create 2 arrays with the size of the parameters that we sent from the function that works to divide the arrays into little pieces.

Well, after sorting the smallest array, how do we combine the new sorted array with the one that we had sorted?

If there is a problem with my question, I am really sorry. Since I'm confused and lost about this part, I have many questions in my mind. Therefore, I may not be clear.

Comment: "Well, after sorting the smallest array, how do we combine the new sorted array with the one that we had sorted?" - this is called the ["merge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), and that's where the name comes from!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo Here's a visual representation :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I watched this video too :D Yet I could not understand the part of merging the arrays :D Till the point that we sort the array, I have no problem. Yet after sorting the smallest array, how do we combine with the second smallest array that we compare as the right array :D

Comment: The merging *is* the sorting of the array, you divide it first to conceptually to arrays of *1*, and any array of *1* is already sorted, so you just *merge* them. The first merge is at 00:40, you compare the lowest elements of the two subarrays and decide which one is smaller, and it goes first into the result array. You repeat this for as long as the two subarrays have elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the visual representation of merge sort, please take a look and you will clearly understand the logic of merge sort. Link:   https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort/visualize/